# How to provide an inline DevOps Powershell task variables which contain special characters

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to run an inline script in a DevOps pipeline (below).  This script is attempting to spawn a PowerShell session with specific credentials in order to run a remote script on the target vm.  In a previous step, the password is obtained from KeyVault ($kvPw in the script below).  However, the password contains a special character, in this case a $.  The devops step looks like this:

```
        inlineScript: |
          az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name $(vmName) -g My-ResourceGroup --scripts `
        "`$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString '$(kvPw)' -AsPlainText -Force" `
        "`$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'vmName\adminUser',`$pw" `
        "Start-Process PowerShell -Cred `$cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File','C:\test\deploy.ps1'"
```

The PowerShell script generated from the above that is stored and executed on the vm is:

```
    $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PeGiewRY1MAQ8)>U?N,T]BLFkLp' -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'vmName\adminUser',$pw
    Start-Process PowerShell -Cred $cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File','C:\test\deploy.ps1'
```

The job step in devops runs successfully, however on closer inspection of the *View Raw Log*, I can see that the script was actually not run due to an *Access is denied* error.

```
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1300587Z     {
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1301041Z       "code": "ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded",
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1301577Z       "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1302112Z       "level": "Info",
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1303733Z       "message": "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the 
error: Access is denied.\nAt 
C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\1.1.8\\Downloads\\script2.ps1:3 
char:1\n+ Start-Process PowerShell -Cred $cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', ...\n+ 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : 
InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand\n ",
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1305283Z       "time": null
2021-03-31T20:28:15.1305668Z     }
```

This is because of the fact that the password that ends up in the script file on the vm is

```
PeGiewRY1MAQ8)>U?N,T]BLFkLp      //while the value stored in KeyVault is:
PeGiewRY1MAQ8)$R>U?N,T]BLFkLp
```

The '$R' is being removed.  How can I structure the inline script in DevOps such that this doesn't happen?  It seems that I need to wrap $(kvPw) in double quotes, but this isn't possible since each line starts/ends with double quotes.

[EDIT]:  Per suggestion by @user19702 below, I tried using double quotes and escaping them as well, but get the error below:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account set --subscription xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx- 
xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile 
-NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 
'C:\agent\_work\_temp\azureclitaskscript1617226948158.ps1'"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

This seems to be a parsing error since the powershell script is not generated on the vm.

Comment: Did you tried with surrounding with single quotes first and then double quotes ? `$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString '"$(kvPw)"' -AsPlainText -Force`

Answer (score 0):

Use double-quotes, but escape them too:

```
"`$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString `"$(kvPw)`" -AsPlainText -Force" `
```

Comment: That's a great thought, gave it a shot, no luck.  See EDIT section above for more info.  Thanks for such a quick response.

Comment: @Mike. Can you run some more tests to see where/if kvPw is being expanded - you may need to add escaped single quotes as well to keep the `$` in the password from getting expanded. Maybe with just a `Echo \`"$(kvPw)\`"` ? I'm not very familiar with azure inline scripts/how many times they will be evaluated, and the error in your edit kind of just says "there was an error"

Answer (score 0):

You could either set the variable as *PeGiewRY1MAQ8)`$R>U?N,T]BLFkLp*, or try something like:

```
$pw = 'set value=''PeGiewRY1MAQ8)$R>U?N,T]BLFkLp'' '
```